# Rails CouchDB App not working in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchdb

I deployed my app on production server and get the following error :

(There was a problem with your config/couchdb.yml file. Check and make sure it's present and the syntax is correct.)

the couchdb.yml file is as follows :

```
base: &base
 database_prefix: 
 database_suffix: _<%%= RAILS_ENV %>

development:
  host: localhost
  port: 5984
  <<: *base

test:
  host: localhost
  port: 5984
  <<: *base

  production:
      host: localhost
      port: 5984
      <<: *base
```

and in the boot.rb

```
require 'rubygems'

# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)

require 'bundler/setup' if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])
require 'simply_stored/couch'
CouchPotato::Config.database_name = "http://localhost:5984/thedatabase"
```

The database is already created and works locally; the problem is on production server, all gems are installed; not sure why I'm missing something that I should specify differently for production.. already tried the host as 127.0.0.1 . no luck

The error is thrown on the couchdb_initializer.rb; the code is universal (already generated by gem).

I can run the app using rails server and open using the 3000 port; however I get the first error when using ngingx + passenger trough http://

Answer (score 1):

Does your production `couchdb.yml` actually have "all:" in it? If so, try setting it to "production:" it looks like that code doesn't have any special logic in place to figure out that the "all" environment in the `couchdb.yml` file should really apply to all environments when it is specifically looking for "production".

Comment: added
production:
        host:localhost
        port:5984
        database:thedatabase

restarted nginx, same error . i am using passenger + nginx

Comment: Not sure then, I tried that yaml file text, and it parsed it ok, so the error wasn't raised at that point. Throwing out ideas: couchdb is up and running on the production box? Permissions ok? SElinux not blocking it? Trying to think of other things that might production specific.

Answer (score 1):

The ident on the file was wrong.

```
  production:
      host: localhost
      port: 5984
      <<: *base
```